# Laravel version9.19 and vuejs 3. 2 + vite

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I am working in project with Laravel version9.19 and vuejs3.2 + vite but me display this error:
[image]

My current project was set up such as screenshot[image]:

I am sharing with you how I have made configuration vite in Laravel: In file vite.config.js:`

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                "resources/css/app.css",
                "resources/scss/app.scss",
                "resources/js/app.js",
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

In view's file app.blade.php, I have added @vite like below:`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Laravel VUE CRUD Application - LaravelTuts</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
     @vite(['resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
    @vite(['resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    <h1>Hello Sass</h1>
    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea way me display error above and how I can solve?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and installed `plugin-vue`
please install it by :

```
 npm install @vitejs/plugin-vue
```

then add it to `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            "resources/css/app.css",
            "resources/scss/app.scss",
            "resources/js/app.js",
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Hope it works